# ValueError: shapes (5,640) and (26,26) not aligned: 640 (dim 1) != 26 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I used an extreme learning machine (ELM) model for predicting as a regression. I used K-fold to validate model prediction. But after executing the following code I get this message error:

```
ValueError: shapes (5,640) and (26,26) not aligned: 640 (dim 1) != 26 (dim 0)
```

How can I solve this problem
My code:

```
#---------------------------------(import dataset_without divided)---------

dataset = pd.read_excel("ss.xls")
X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1:]
#----------Scaler----------
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X=scaler.fit_transform(X)

kfolds = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=16, shuffle=False)  

train_folds_idx = []
valid_folds_idx = []

for train_index, valid_index in kfolds.split(dataset.index):
    train_folds_idx.append(train_index)
    valid_folds_idx.append(valid_index)
 
#------------------------INPUT------------------

input_size = X.shape[1]

#---------------------------(Number of neurons)-------
hidden_size = 26

#---------------------------(weights & biases)------------
input_weights = np.random.normal(size=[input_size,hidden_size])
biases = np.random.normal(size=[hidden_size])

#----------------------(Activation Function)----------
def relu(x):
   return np.maximum(x, 0, x)

#--------------------------(Calculations)----------
def hidden_nodes(X):
    G = np.dot(X, input_weights)
    G = G + biases
    H = relu(G)
    return H

#Output weights 

output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(train_folds_idx)), valid_folds_idx)


#------------------------(Def prediction)---------
def predict(X):
    out = hidden_nodes(X)
    out = np.dot(out, output_weights)
    return out

#------------------------------------(Make_PREDICTION)--------------

prediction = predict(valid_folds_idx)
```

Comment: Does the error message indicate which line of code caused the problem?   That'd be helpful in sussing out what's going on.

Comment: ```640 (dim 1) != 26 (dim 0)``` this part hints at a problem with the ```G = np.dot(X, input_weights)``` in the ```hidden_nodes()``` function. For a dot product you can only perform it on matrices of dimensions a X b & b X c where the number of columns in the first matrix must equal the number of rows in the second.

Comment: ... or below in the other two ```np.dot()``` functions

Comment: The error message indicts to the following lines :    output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(train_folds_idx)), valid_folds_idx)                                                      and in line :      G = np.dot(X, input_weights)   @ Mark Lavin

Comment: Thank you, ok. So How can I solve this problem and how should I write the code? @ Chaos_Is_Harmony